# Fetching still image from Instagram reel

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am trying to fetch an image of a video reel from instagram using webkit. I am able to fetch my user picture without issues, however I am unable to fetch reel pictures. After a little of investigation, I found that every reel has a unique uri identifier. So I was able to write a javascript code and fetch the link in console as can be seen bellow I successfully retrieved the image URL.
[image]

JavaScript code (https://www.instagram.com/p/CyzX0mCJtmn/):

```
(function() {
    var anchorElement = document.querySelector('a[href="/p/CyzX0mCJtmn/"]');
    if (anchorElement) {
        var imgElement = anchorElement.querySelector('div._aagu img');
        return imgElement ? imgElement.getAttribute('src') : "Image not found";
    }
    return "No anchor element found with identifier: CyzX0mCJtmn";
})();
```

With that I attempted to write a simple Swift code to do the same thing, I have the webkit load the website and wait few seconds and then attempt to fetch the link. The code is using identifier as a parser to strip the url and only use the identifier to properly locate the html element. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var urlInput: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var webViewStore = WebViewStore()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer() // Push content to the bottom
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                if let uiImage = webViewStore.fetchedUIImage {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Divider()

            HStack {
                TextField("Enter URL", text: $urlInput)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                Button("Load") {
                    if let validURL = URL(string: urlInput) {
                        webViewStore.load(url: validURL)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class WebViewStore: NSObject, ObservableObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    @Published var fetchedUIImage: UIImage?
    var uniqueIdentifier: String?  // Store the unique identifier
    var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        return webView
    }()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    func load(url: URL) {
        // Extract the unique identifier from the given URL
        let components = url.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/")
        if components.count > 4 {
            uniqueIdentifier = components[4]
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Wait for a few seconds to give the webpage additional time to load before attempting to fetch the image URL
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7.0) {
            self.attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: 3)
        }
    }
    
    private func attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: Int) {
        if retryCount <= 0 {
            print("Max retry count reached.")
            return
        }
        
        let checkScript = "document.body.innerHTML.includes('Instagram')"
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(checkScript) { (result, error) in
                if let isPresent = result as? Bool, isPresent {
                    if let urlStr = self.webView.url?.absoluteString {
                        self.fetchImageURL(from: urlStr, retryCount: retryCount)
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Did not find 'Instagram' in the body. Retrying... Remaining retries: \(retryCount-1)")
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        self.attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: retryCount - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func fetchImageURL(from url: String, retryCount: Int) {
        let identifier = url.components(separatedBy: "/").filter { !$0.isEmpty }.last ?? ""
        let fetchImageScript = """
        (function() {
            var anchorElement = document.querySelector('a[href="/p/\(identifier)/"]');
            if (anchorElement) {
                var imgElement = anchorElement.querySelector('div._aagu img');
                return imgElement ? imgElement.getAttribute('src') : "Image not found";
            }
            return "No anchor element found with identifier: \(identifier)";
        })();
        """
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(fetchImageScript) { (fetchResult, fetchError) in
            if let link = fetchResult as? String, link != "Image not found", let validURL = URL(string: link) {
                print("Successfully fetched image URL: \(link)")
                self.loadImage(from: validURL)
            } else {
                print("Failed to fetch image URL with error: \(fetchResult ?? "Unknown error")")
                if retryCount > 0 {
                    self.retryFetching(retryCount: retryCount - 1)
                } else {
                    print("Max retry attempts reached.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func retryFetching(retryCount: Int) {
        print("Retrying... Remaining retries: \(retryCount-1).")
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            self.attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: retryCount - 1)
        }
    }
    private func loadImage(from url: URL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let imageData = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fetchedUIImage = uiImage
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Despite that I am able to fetch it with javascript and console and also using python and selenium I cannot achieve it using Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swift code actually works, and I made it work by replacing your javascript code with this:

```
    let fetchImageScript = """
        (function() {
            var anchorElement = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
            if (anchorElement) {
                return anchorElement.getAttribute('content')
            }
        return "No anchor element found with identifier: CyzX0mCJtmn";
        })();
    """
```

I adjusted to grab the thumb image of the instagram post to show that it works below.

So the problem is the javascript that is looking for a specific class, in your case `"div._aagu"`, which I suspect dynamically change each time, so if you insert the correct javascript, your app should work.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it did work. I was able to change it to dynamic load and seems good to go. I also had a question, since the image and the description and hashtags are in the same element, how would you extract it? I tried og:description but it only gave me partial result @Vali Zairov

Comment: It's actually here:
<meta property="og:title" content="Ethix ltd on Instagram: &quot;&#064;merlin_fpv \\ Pilgrim //
&#x2022;
The NYC trip was a blast! Soooo good to catch up with the homies. Ive got some footy to go through but heres a little sample from the mighty Pilgrim &#x1f918;
&#x2022;..." />

Comment: that was it, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: dang it I just figured that the og:image fetches only partially cropped image for some reason. Because if you run the app and fetch the link and open it in a browser you will see how its cropped, but if you run the javascript in console you will see the full size. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you run the javascript it also shows the square preview, I think it is used when showing a thumbnail preview in the grid view. You have to find a way to extract the image path first. I believe it is being loaded via script.